# R Function %*% Explanation

Tags: r, matrix

I have a small Data Frame that looks like below -

```
Name,StAndrewsLodge,LoyalNine,NorthCaucus,LongRoomClub,TeaParty,BostonCommittee,LondonEnemies
Adams.John,0,0,1,1,0,0,0
Adams.Samuel,0,0,1,1,0,1,1
Allen.Dr,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
Appleton.Nathaniel,0,0,1,0,0,1,0
data <- as.matrix(read.csv("data.csv",row.names=1))
data.t = t(data)
```

Once this is imported into a R Data Set, we can transpose it using the t() function.

Post that we create a new data set using

```
data.ts = data %*% t(data)
```

I am trying to understand what the %*% function does. The numbers that come out also make no sense.

If someone has used this can you pls explain.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Matrix multiplication, see `help("%*%")`.

> Multiplies two matrices, if they are conformable. If one argument is a vector, it will be promoted to either a row or column matrix to make the two arguments conformable. If both are vectors of the same length, it will return the inner product (as a matrix).